# How to change header navigation in pligg cms

Tags: php

I am not find out the way how to change the header navigation in `pligg` according to my requirment.The current header navigation is given below

`PUBLISHED NEWS|UPCOMING NEWS | SUBMIT A NEW STORY |GROUPS |PROFILE |ADMIN`

that was the bydefault navigation I want to change this navigation.I want remove some tab from this navigation given above and also want to add new tab.Is this manageable through admin

Answer (score 1):

You will have to edit the template file \templates\TEMPLATE_NAME\header.tpl

You will have to find and modify accordingly the followin section:

```
<!-- START NAVBAR -->
<ul id="nav">
...
TAB1
TAB2
...
</ul>
```

That can be done through admin site : Home › Admin › Template -> Template editor

Comment: Ok fine and thanks for reply  but its work like static mean is there any functionality from admin user just add tab at backend and it will be reflected  on frontend.